# Alembic - Create sequential migrations

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

My Git flow consists of `develop`, `master` and `feature` branches. I use Alembic for database migrations, and I run migrations **only after** merging branches into master.

Currently, merging a branch containing migrations into `develop` causes trouble. Here is the problematic process:

1. New branch off of `develop` (BRANCH 1)
2. Create migrations in BRANCH 1
3. Merge BRANCH 1 into `develop`
4. The migrations aren't being run because they are not in `master`
5. Another new branch off of `develop` for a different feature (BRANCH 2)
6. Now, it's impossible to create migrations in BRANCH 2 - I get `Target database is not up to date` because the `head` revision is the new revision created in #1, but the database has not been upgraded yet.

Running `alembic history` gives:

```
c4892151a825 -> 3451e691af8a (head), BRANCH 1
c4a0d473218e -> c4892151a825, MASTER MIGRATIONS
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the two migrations run sequentially:

```
c4892151a825 -> 3451e691a4jf BRANCH 2
c4892151a825 -> 3451e691af8a BRANCH 1
... -> c4892151a825, (head), MASTER MIGRATIONS
```

I tried running `alembic revision --head c4892151a825`, but it says that the revision is not a `head` revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution:

1. move BRANCH 1 migration file to a different location
2. Create a new revision.
3. Return the migration file to the previous location and merge the two using `alembic merge`.